# Can you rearrange items without using touch?

Tags: nintendo-switch, loop-hero

With Loop Hero coming to the Switch, it brings some controller support which works mostly. However there seems to be a limitation to it. Normally pressing <kbd>ZR</kbd> moves the cursor to your inventory so you can equip items, but there doesn't seem to be a way to rearrange your items. This can be problematic if there's a particular item you want to hold on to a while longer that you don't want to use at the moment.

Is there a way to rearrange the items without resorting to using the touch screen?